# How to update nested array's value in mongoDB or Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data in `mongoDB` as follows

```
_id : 5d91caf461f93f13e48ac307,
restaurants : [
    {
        name : 'grace restaurant',
        menus : [
            {
                menu_name : 'chicken soup',
                price : 100
            },
            {
                menu_name : 'Biriyani',
                price : 250
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name : 'river side restaurant',
        menus : [
            {
                menu_name : 'veg lollipop',
                price : 47
            },
            {
                menu_name : 'Grill chicken',
                price : 210
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, I need to update the `river side restaurant's` menu "`Grill chicken's`" price to 310.

How can I do that with `mongoose` or `mongoDB` function,I have used lot of different functions but no use, Please help me to find this.

Thank you

Comment: May be this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ in the part of "Update Embedded Documents Using Multiple Field Matches" can help you to find the way

The ``$`` operator can update the first array element that matches multiple query criteria specified with the $elemMatch() operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use the array filters for the same.

**The following is an example:**

```
db.collection.update({},
{
    $set:{
        "restaurants.$[restaurantFilter].menus.$[menuFilter].price": 310
    }
},
{
    "arrayFilters":[
        {
            "restaurantFilter.name":"river side restaurant"
        },
        {
            "menuFilter.menu_name":"Grill chicken"
        }
    ]
})
```

**Before update:**

```
{
    "_id" : "5d91caf461f93f13e48ac307",
    "restaurants" : [
        {
            "name" : "grace restaurant",
            "menus" : [
                {
                    "menu_name" : "chicken soup",
                    "price" : 100
                },
                {
                    "menu_name" : "Biriyani",
                    "price" : 250
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "river side restaurant",
            "menus" : [
                {
                    "menu_name" : "veg lollipop",
                    "price" : 47
                },
                {
                    "menu_name" : "Grill chicken",
                    "price" : 210
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**After update:**

```
{
    "_id" : "5d91caf461f93f13e48ac307",
    "restaurants" : [
        {
            "name" : "grace restaurant",
            "menus" : [
                {
                    "menu_name" : "chicken soup",
                    "price" : 100
                },
                {
                    "menu_name" : "Biriyani",
                    "price" : 250
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "river side restaurant",
            "menus" : [
                {
                    "menu_name" : "veg lollipop",
                    "price" : 47
                },
                {
                    "menu_name" : "Grill chicken",
                    "price" : 310
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please put your response of this query if you tested it?

Comment: @abdulbarik Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much brother,It's working now...Thanks Alot

Comment: @EmmanuelR Please accept the answer if it seems perfect to you.